# Помогите нарисовать сегмент круга

Tags: html, вёрстка, scss, border

[image: нужны таке округленные углы]

Не могу создать такие углы, пробовал так:

```
border-radius: 100px 100px 0px 0px / 119px 16px 0px 0px;
```

но не могу никак выровнять...

Comment: всмысле тебе нужно уменьшить его или что? или нужно сделать неидеальный круг?

Comment: @Мнебезсахара
нужно скруглить верхние углы точно  как на изображении. 
левый и правый скругленные, нижние нет
Я сделал так: 
border-radius: 160% 100% 60% 70%/100% 25% 0% 0%;
Но переход не плавный как на изображении

Comment: Попробуй смастерить в фотошопе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Border radius Figure generetor](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-radius_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) вам в помощь.

Comment: А что? так можно было? :) 
Спасибо, почти то что нужно, он все равно посредине сверху не выходит сделать выпуклость как на изображении.

Answer (score 0):

что то такое? просто я незнаю какие размеры у синего шара

```css
.div{
background-color:#261EBE;
width:600px;
height:600px;
border-radius: 356px 230px 72px 61px / 150px 106px 34px 43px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "div"></div>
```

Comment: Герератор который оставил @Bookamba почти решил вопрос) 
Ваше решение тоже подходит, спасибо